# Insertar porcentajes o valores numéricos en bar plots y pie charts R

Tags: r

¿Alguna idea de cómo insertar porcentajes en pie charts / bar plots?

El código es un código típico de barplot, no sé si puedo agregar algo más directamente para hacer que los valores aparezcan:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(becal_completo$categoriauni)), 
col = c("yellow", "blue", "orange", "red", "green"), ylim=c(0,0.9), 
main="Ranking universidades becarixs BECAL", ylab ="")
```

Comment: Para que se te pueda ayudar edita la pregunta y muestra con código lo que has intentado

Comment: Ahora lo agregue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que pusieras algo de código respecto a cosas que hayas intentando con el fin de obtener retroalimentación. Sin embargo, te dejo un ejemplo reproducible específicamente para barplots ya que trabajé en ello hace algún tiempo

```
#Creamos una data.frame simple
myvar <- c(0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,12,12,17,17,20)
myvar <- data.frame(myvar)
myvar

#Ordenamos valores (este paso no es necesario pero es ilustrativo para el caso)
myvar2 <- ordered(myvar$myvar, levels = c(0,6,9,12,17,20),labels = c("Muy bajo", "Bajo", "Medio bajo", "Medio", "Medio alto", "Alto"))  
myvar2


#Creamos una tabla que será nuestra base para el plot
options(digits=3)
EP <- table(myvar2)
EP
EP <- prop.table(EP)*100


#Barplots
par(cex.axis= 0.7, cex.lab= 0.5, cex.sub= 0.7, las=1)   
bp1<- barplot(EP, main="Nivel alcanzado", col="aliceblue", ylim=c(0,60), cex.main=0.8)
text(bp1, EP+2,format(EP), cex=0.7)
```

Con esto tendrás una imagen como esta: (Perdón por la mala calidad)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrás observar, para lo que requieres lo que importa es la función `text`. Dado que text funciona bajo un formato text(x,y), tu x en este caso es la asignación a bp1. El segundo argumento te da la posición del texto respecto al eje y. Si usas `EP+2`, indicas que te refieres al valor de esa barra +2 posiciones arriba. El tercer argumento `format(EP)` le indica a R que el formato para asignar los valores a las barras será el que aparece en la tabla `EP`. Finalmente, con `cex` controlas el tamaño del texto, aunque puedes omitirlo y dejar el tamaño por default.

Espero esto pueda ayudarte en algo. Para el caso de pie-chart, bien puedes referirte a este sitio y encontrarás cosas interesantes

https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Alejando! una consulta, ahora agregué el codigo que estoy utilizando arriba, te lo posteo igual más abajo de nuevo, alguna forma de utilizar text dentro del mismo compando barplot o si o si se utiliza text por separado asignado el barplot a un nuevo elemento? Saludos!         
                       
        barplot(prop.table(table(becal_completo$categoriauni)), 
        col = c("yellow", "blue", "orange", "red", "green"), ylim=c(0,0.9), 
        main="Ranking universidades becarixs BECAL", ylab ="")

Comment: text va por fuera de la llamada a barplot ya que es una función aplicable a otros objetos. Por eso, cuando usas text(x,y) tu x es el objeto barplot creado.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a ver si logro utilizarlo, o sino te sigo preguntando

Comment: Será un gusto ayudarte. Saludos :)